# RequireJS not working with commonjs require syntax

Tags: javascript, requirejs, commonjs

I'm trying to get RequireJS working using the commonjs `var mod=require("mod");` syntax and getting this error:

`Uncaught Error: Module name "mod" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])`

The [documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded) for this error states:

> If the error message includes Use require([]), then it was a top-level require call (not a require call inside a define() call) that should be using the async, callback version of require to load the code

But this isn't true for my code - the require line is within a call to `define`.

Here is my stripped-down test code:

test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Require JS test</title>
        <script data-main="main" src="require.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

main.js:

```
define(function() {
    var mod=require("mod");
});
```

mod.js:

```
define(function() {
    return {
        prop: 123
    };
});
```

require.js is version 2.1.9 - http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.9/comments/require.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use it like this:

main js:

```
require(['mod'], function(mod) {
     console.log(mod.prop);
});
```

otherwise use:

main.js:

```
define(function(require) {
    var mod = require("mod");
});
```

Comment: I am interested in why the way I'm doing it now doesn't work.

Comment: i think you were just missing the require arg in your define function

Comment: `var mod = require("mod");` won't work as `require` is async use `define(["mod"], function(mod, require) {`

Comment: @megawac : you shouldn't require mod first, you should use `define(["require","mod"], function(require,mod) {});` instead, but the example above works too.